# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref.navigation')

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am not able to rectify this error.
I have reinstalled node_modules, but no use can anyone please help me with this issue??
[Complete error is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRzrr.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the relevant part of the code and include your errors as text and not as an image.

Comment: are you using a functional component or class component?

Answer (score 1):

are you using a functional component or class component? I think JS bundle is not able to find the reference for the navigation.
Try with this

```
this.navigation = React.createRef();
```

in the constructor.
Please post the error in detail.

Comment: I am using functional component, and my issue solved thanks 

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes here, since @Naresh didn't say what they did to solve it, I just updated my packages. I was using bun so I ran: `bun add ...` and then the name of the packages but you can do `npm install ...` and then the name of each package. Or to make sure that a package is installed you can do: `npm ls ...` and then the name of the package and that will list the package if that package is found